# Taking big chunk of Time while Running K means on Python Spark

Tags: pyspark

I have a nparray vector with 0s and 1s with 37k rows and 6k columns.
When I try to run Kmeans Clustering in Pyspark, it takes almost forever to load and I cannot get the output. Is there any way to reduce the processing time or any other tricks to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you may have too many columns, you could have faced the **dimensionality course**. [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality)

> [...] The common theme of these problems is that when the dimensionality increases, the volume of the space increases so fast that the available data become sparse. This sparsity is problematic for any method that requires statistical significance. In order to obtain a statistically sound and reliable result, the amount of data needed to support the result often grows exponentially with the dimensionality. [...]

In order to solve this problem, did you consider reducing your columns, using only relevant ones? Check again this [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensionality_reduction)

> [...] Feature projection transforms the data in the high-dimensional space to a space of fewer dimensions. The data transformation may be linear, as in principal component analysis (PCA), but many nonlinear dimensionality reduction techniques also exist. [...]